# How do you get a file from a windows host to linux docker container?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, docker, dockerfile

I've been trying things like

docker run -t -i -v c/my-project:/usr/share/my-project mp /bin/bash

(mp is the name of my container) and

docker run -t -i -v c/my-project:/usr/share/my-project:Z mp /bin/bash,

but while a directory my-project is created in the docker image, it is always empty despite the fact the directory is not empty in Windows.

I've resorted to adding the files in the Dockerfile build with RUN mkdir and ADD c/my-project but that is sub-optimal.

Comment: Where is your Linux vm running? Volume mounting only works for some setups, eg. Docker Toolbox with VirtualBox (and then only with folders in your User folder) and with Docker for Windows.

Comment: You should try the new docker beta for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot host Linux Docker containers directly on Windows. There is a Linux VM host that 'Docker machine'/boot2docker created for you. You will have to transfer your files to the VM.

I don't recommend using Docker machine due to frustrations with ip and filesystem mapping. Just explicitly create your own Linux VM and manage Docker that way.